# " the argument type jsobject cannot be assigned to parameter type BuildContext"

Tags: flutter, dart

this is the main.dart code where error occurred

```dart
theme: MyTheme.lightTheme(context: context),
```

And this is the function that I made

```dart
static ThemeData lightTheme({BuildContext context}) =>
  ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
    primaryColor: Colors.deepPurple,
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      bodyText1: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.deepPurple,
      ),
      bodyText2: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.deepPurple,
      )
    )
  );
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Whatever `context` is that you are passing to `MyTheme.lightTheme` isn't a `BuildContext`. What it actually is is a mystery to us.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the curly braces "{}" from around the `BuildContext context`.

```dart
static ThemeData lightTheme(BuildContext context) =>
  ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
    primaryColor: Colors.deepPurple,
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      bodyText1: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.deepPurple,
      ),
      bodyText2: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.deepPurple,
      )
    )
  );
```